# How to change color format in Firefox Dev Tools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

In Chrome Dev Tools, I can Shift+Click on a color in the inspector to change the formats (Hex -> RGB -> HSL). Can I do that in Firefox Dev Tools? I can change the *default* format in the settings but I just need to copy the color value in another format in one instance.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but related. To set permanently, set
`"hex" in about:config under "devtools.defaultColorUnit"`

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4kk454/comment/d3g4rat/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For those coming across this later, like I did: [it has now shipped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Inspect_and_select_colors). You can change colour by **holding Shift and clicking** the colour sample (i.e. the circle filled with the colour).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that at the moment in Firefox DevTools, but this is being worked on as we speak. You can follow along the development here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136257
I expect this to land for Firefox 40.

Comment: Another reasons to switch to Chrome I wait 15 years to solve Bug 132035 - Implement missing page-break,  and no progress